# trying to set cookie in jsonresponse django

Tags: django, cookies

Hello I am trying to set a JWT token in a cookie in a jsonresponse when people login.
this is my current code.

```
response = JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'user': user})
                response.set_cookie(
                    key='access_token', 
                    value=tokens["access"],
                    max_age=900,
                    domain='localhost',
                    path='/',
                    # secure=False,
                    # httponly=True,
                    # samesite='Lax'
                )
                return response
```

In my browser the cookie is never set. in my netwerk tab when i look at the login request i do see the cookie.
Here are the headers of my request.
[image]

And here you can find the cookies that are set in the browser.

[image]

all help is greatly apprectiated.